# NetMQ On A Network

Tags: c#, network-programming, netmq

I'm trying to do messaging between programs on separate computers on a local network. The design is basically one "server," multiple "clients," with the server sending messages to the clients and receiving messages from the clients, and the clients receiving messages from the server, and sending/receiving client messages between each other.

I'm trying to use NetMQ for this, but I'm having trouble getting it working on a network. I can run the server and client programs perfectly fine on a single machine, but I'm not sure how to get it to work on a network, and I can't find any NetMQ examples that show this--to be clear, **every** example I can find uses "localhost" or some other IP address for **both** the "publisher" and "subscriber" (I'm using a Pub-Sub pattern, but I've seen the same regardless of the pattern used in the example).

Some example code using the client-client framework (this requires an XPub-XSub framework because there are multiple publishers and subscribers):

```
NetMQPoller poller = new NetMQPoller();
PublisherSocket clientPub = new PublisherSocket("tcp://*:4444");
XPublisherSocket xPub = new XPublisherSocket("tcp://*:5555");
XSubscriberSocket xSub = new XSubscriberSocket("tcp://*:4444");
Proxy proxy = new proxy(xSub, xPub, poller: poller);
proxy.Start();
SubscriberSocket clientSub = new SubscriberSocket("tcp://*:5555");
poller.Add(clientSub);
poller.Add(clientPub);
poller.RunAsync();
```

If I run this, I get "the application is in break mode" with the following error:

> NetMQ.NetMQException   HResult=0x80131500   Source=NetMQ   StackTrace:
>   at NetMQ.Core.Transports.Tcp.TcpConnector.OutCompleted(SocketError
>   socketError, Int32 bytesTransferred)    at
>   NetMQ.Core.IOObject.OutCompleted(SocketError socketError, Int32
>   bytesTransferred)    at NetMQ.Core.Utils.Proactor.Loop()    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

If I change the clientSub's address to "tcp://127.0.0.1:5555" it starts fine. However, **that won't work** because the subscriber needs to receive messages from any machine on the network.

How do I do this with NetMQ? Can anyone provide a working example of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default when you use the constructor of a socket is either bind or connect, depends on the socket type. publisher bind (listen)and subscriber connects. So it does make sense to use * for the subscriber.

You are using tcp transport, so you have to specify an ip address of the remote peer when connecting. If you want to connect to multiple publishers you can either call connect or provide s string with multiple addresses separated by comma.

Bottom line instead of *, localhost or 127.0.0.1 use the ip address of the publisher machine.

You can use the @ or > prefixes to override the defaults of the constructor. @ to bind and > to connect.

```
NetMQPoller poller = new NetMQPoller();
PublisherSocket clientPub = new PublisherSocket(">tcp://192.168.0.15:4444");
XPublisherSocket xPub = new XPublisherSocket("@tcp://*:5555");
XSubscriberSocket xSub = new XSubscriberSocket("@tcp://*:4444");
Proxy proxy = new proxy(xSub, xPub, poller: poller);
proxy.Start();
SubscriberSocket clientSub = new SubscriberSocket(">tcp://192.168.0.15:5555");
poller.Add(clientSub);
poller.Add(clientPub);
poller.RunAsync();
```

192.168.0.15 is my ip address. You need to change it to your ip.

Comment: The idea of connecting to multiple endpoints from a subscriber never occurred to me. Thanks. Just for clarity, is the only way to do that with clientSub.Connect() multiple times? I just tried clientSub = new SubscriberSocket(">tcp//*:5555") and I got a NetMQException again.

Comment: '>' is for connecting, you cannot connect to '*', '*' is used as any when binding, when connecting you have to use ip address or DNS.

Answer (score 1):

I have a simple example. My "server" code runs on a Amazon EC2 instance. It listens on port 11000 and responds to a single message.

```
using System;
using NetMQ;
using NetMQ.Sockets;

class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    { 
        using (var server = new ResponseSocket("@tcp://*:11000"))
        {
            // the server receives, then sends
            Console.WriteLine("From Client: {0}", server.ReceiveFrameString());
            server.SendFrame("Hi Back");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

My Client code runs on my PC:

```
using System;
using NetMQ;
using NetMQ.Sockets;

class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        using (var client = new RequestSocket(">tcp://3.13.186.250:11000"))
        {
            client.SendFrame("Hello");
            Console.WriteLine("From Server: {0}", client.ReceiveFrameString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```